# NEXT.js isomorphic-unfetch errs out

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am doing the following exercise on [Next.js remote fetching](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows). What I am not able to understand and adapt is the exercise fetches data from [http://api.tvmaze.com](http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=batman).

Data is like:

```
[
 {"score":24,"show":{"id":975,"url":"", "name":""}}
,{"score":25,"show":{"id":976,"url":"", "name":""}}
,{"score":26,"show":{"id":977,"url":"", "name":""}}
]
```

The index page uses the following mapping:

```
{props.shows.map(({show}) => (
        <li key={show.id}>
          <Link as={'/p/${show.id}'} href={'/post?id=${show.id}'}>
            <a>{show.name}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
```

Note, it has `{"score":"", "show":{}}` structure. So, the `props.shows.map` uses a variable `show` and refers to `show.id` and `show.name`. And it works fine. I am confused to understand how does it work? Because `id` is nestled inside and to me it should be `show.show.id`.

Also, I am trying to fetch a different source of data that has slightly different structure.

```
[
 {"id": 1, "name":"name1"}
,{"id": 2, "name":"name2"}
,{"id": 3, "name":"name3"}
]
```

The same code fails with error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

So, apart from it has obviously different data structure. I could not understand why, if my data structure is *slightly* different, how do I change the `props.shows.map` function change accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with object destructuring in JS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

In the example, writing `({show})` is shorthand for writing something like `(resp)` and then later `show = resp.show`. So in this case, due to destructuring, `show` already *is* the `show` object. Therefore, `id` works.

Your data doesn't have a `show` property, so when destructuring, `show` is undefined. And, of course, you can't get a property of `undefined`. Removing the curly braces from `{show}` should do the trick.

Comment: That's true. It did the trick. Glad you explained what it is as well.